# Ergonomic wall arms for home office. What are my options?

Tags: ergonomics

I am allowed to work 1-2 days a week from home. I work with a computer 6-8 hours a day. We have one corner in a living room that I would like to transform into into my home office with a monitor, a PC and a keyboard. I am looking for a solution that would take little space while still would be ergonomic.

I have found a wall arm interesting, because I can push it to the wall when I am not working. Still, I have doubts whether it is ergonomic enough. For instance, with traditional desk I can rest my palms and forearms on it.

[image: Wall arm for monitor and keyboard]

Second thing is that, from time to time, I use the same computer to work with drawing tablet. I wonder if there are wall arms that have enough space to hold it.

What are my options?

Comment: Why can't you simply use a table and put away your equipment when you've finished?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace SE! Unfortunately I'm not sure that product recommendations are in scope here, and really only you can know what's going to fit in your living room and what would be comfortable for you. FWIW the example you gave looks like it would be horribly uncomfortable to work on for any length of time for me!

Comment: That picture itself makes me feel uncomfortable, I can't imagine actually using it. Don't fall for marketing gimmicks. Get a regular table (with wheels if you prefer) and put it away once your work is done. Using the living room as an office also seems less desirable because it would be too distracting, but if that floats your boat ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a shopping question rather than how to negotiate the workplace.

Comment: At any rate, this might be a better fit for the Home Improvement site ( https://diy.stackexchange.com/ ). They have a lot of furniture questions.

Comment: @MaskedMan. Re: "Using the living room as an office also seems less desirable because it would be too distracting, but if that floats your boat ". With a living room, small sleeping room and balcony that's the only option, unless I decide to work from the toilet.

Comment: @dzieciou Of course, I didn't mean there was anything *wrong* with it, you know what works for you best.

Comment: Whether something is ergonomic or not depends on your criteria for ergonomics. Here: http://capsoff.wikidot.com/checklist are some suggested for input devices, which could be useful in this case, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use one of these wall arms.  As you can see, they're more for occasional use than to be ergonomic. It's just going to rattle and wobble when you type and there's no room for resting your arms or any paperwork.  I imagine that more expensive ones might have a cup-holder (if you're lucky).  And you'll end up with big holes in your living room wall when you want to remove it.

A far more practical solution is to obtain a small collapsible table that you can put all of your equipment on.  this will allow you to work in comfort without too much disruption to the rest of the house.  When your two days work is done, you can simply fold up the table and put it away somewhere for the other 5 days.

Or you can use your dining table.  This is what I do - I have plenty of room and I'm comfortable.

Comment: I have a computer desk in a cabinet. I can just close it up.

Comment: @HLGEM I started to review such solutions and I wonder lots of examples of folding wall desks and wall cabinets with folding desks. Are you able to fit big LCD monitor into it?

Comment: It would depend on the furniture and the monitor. The one I have fits a large monitor but would not fit the two large monitors I use for my work computer.  You just need to measure to know what you need in terms of size and then only consider the ones that meet that basic criteria.

Answer (score 0):

> I have doubts whether it is ergonomic enough.

"Ergonomic enough" is always in the eye of the beholder.

To me, this looks terribly uncomfortable. It isn't something I would do for 6-8 hours a day. But, like keyboards, only you can decide if it feels good for you.

Go to the store and try it out for as long as you can. Try to notice how your hands and arms feel. Then decide.